# Shell script works in bash but not in ksh

Tags: bash, shell, ksh

I need to write a script to test if the command blablabla exists in the classpath. So I wrote the following code:

```
if ! hash blablabla >/dev/null 2>&1; then
   echo not found
fi
```

This works fine when the script is executed in the bash. But if I try it in KSH, then it doesn't work:

```
#! /usr/bin/ksh

if ! hash blablabla >/dev/null 2>&1; then
   echo not found
fi
```

I expect the `echo not found` to be executed but instead I get nothing. What's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe *command* is portable (if that matters):

```
command -v -- some_command >/dev/null 2>&1 ||
  printf '%s\n' "not found"
```

Comment: @glenn jackman, yes, thanks for pointing it out. Some shells implement it as whence alias, but it's standard.

Answer (score 3):

In bash `hash` is a builtin command. In ksh it's an alias; aliases aren't active in shell scripts.

```
alias hash='alias -t --'
```

Try the `which` command, which is an external command and therefore shell-independent:

```
if ! which -s blablabla; then
    echo not found >&2
fi
```

Comment: You are right about hash being an alias for KSH. Thanks for the info! But unfortunatelly the which command doesn't have the -s in the server that I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

Tha `hash` command is a shell built-in command in `bash`, but not in `ksh`. You might want to use `whence` instead.

```
if ! whence blah; then print urgh; fi
```

Comment: The whence is only available for ksh. I need it to work on bash too.

Comment: @Rodrigo: Why? Are you writing a script? In that case, just specify with a hash-bang (`#!`) at the top what shell to run the script in, e.g., `#!/bin/ksh` to use Korn shell. I treat different shells as different programming languages. That way I do not try to make [polyglot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyglot_(computing)) programs. This tends to make scripts cleaner.